# Can we get TestNG report showing whether test class has pass or fail

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

Can we get testNG report showing particular test class as been pass/ fail , as for now report is showing only method pass / fail not class level. IF we can get TestNG report then how for class level pass and fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Testng listener to customize your report and create a html report template to showcase results. You can get test result on class level as mentioned below.

```
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    log("\nSuccess\n");
    String className = result.getInstanceName();      
    log(className);
}
```

This is an example to use listener onTestSuccess. In same manner you can use **onTestFailure**, **onTestSkipped** listeners for test fail and skip.

Here you can check how to do testng report’s customization.

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example

Comment: I have tried the following code by attaching that to reports using Reporter.log, but again its displaying data on test method level. I need to know that if all methods in class is passed the class should be pass or Fail message displaying

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@AfterClass
public void tearDown(ITestContext context){
    if(context.getFailedTests().size())>0){
       System.out.println("at least one test failed");
    else{
       System.out.println("all tests were success");
    }
```